# What is the reason for whispering a wish in God's ear?

Tags: worship, temple, prayer

We often see people whispering in a deity's ear like in the image below:

[image: whisper in deity's ear]

Normally, when we visit the temple we simply close our eyes and pray or tell our wish to God. But some people do the above action as well.

Does it have any special meaning?

Comment: what I think its just manyata ... let see what others have to say, we can agree with 'NANDI' in this case, but not Ganesha.

Comment: The one force that is more powerful among people than the Veda itself - Popular Custom.

Comment: I once asked this to a pujari, he said to me that we close one ear of statue and whisper in other in order to have god's complete focus/attention on my wish. Idea is that many people in many temple could be asking wishes at the same time. This act just give us a kind of special preference/attention.